# ldap vbscript : msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable is randomly missing on different accounts

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server, exchange-server-2003

In my script:

```
Function getDescript (strname, uname) 

    Set MyUser = GetObject ("LDAP://cn=" & uname & ",ou=" & strname & ",DC=tms-1,DC=net")

getDescript = myUser.Get("msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable")
End Function

uname = "Bob Gardner"
strname = "bgConsultants"

WScript.Echo "wireless enable: " & getDescript(strname, uname)
```

I have noticed some users in the same OU sometimes do and sometimes don't have the msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable attribute when I check it in sysinternals' ACtive Directory Explorer.  All users are in the same OU and the exchange 2003 server has sp2 installed.

Anyone might know why this is?

*Update: 
I figured out that if I disable and re-enable the Outlook Mobile Access setting for each user, the msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable attribute shows up again for those users missing that attribute...weird..*

Comment: even enabling and disabling users outlook mobile access user setting doesn't always create the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, By default, when you install Microsoft Exchange Server 2003, the option to permit all users to use Microsoft Outlook Mobile Access is turned on in Active Directory Users and Computers. So this would leave me to believe that this value is only prensent fo an account inwhich the setting has been toggled.  You could probably do an easy ADSI to return back only the users that don't have this setting set, or not set to enable see here for a good ADSI reference: http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOSearchTips.htm

<s>["By default, when you install Microsoft Exchange Server 2003, the option to permit all users to use Microsoft Outlook Mobile Access is turned on in Active Directory Users and Computers."](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830188)</s>

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right, the user attribute `msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable` value is default empty (oma is working). When oma is disabled the value is 7 (4+2+1), when oma is then enabled again the value is 0. I have made some oma scripts, they can be found at:

http://deludi.nl/blog/vbscript/active-directory/outlookmobileaccess/active-directory-vbscript-to-disable-outlook-mobile-access-oma-for-all-users-in-your-company/